# Copy specific cell that match the condition and paste to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a vba that copy the cell that match my condition and paste it to another sheet but my problem is it copy all rows with that matched with what I am looking for. I only need to copy the cell that matched. Here is my code

```
Sub format()

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value Like "*application_id*" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cell(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy` You are copying a row. So how will it copy just the cell?

Comment: Yes, but when I changed the Rows(i) to Cell(i) it shows error 1004

Comment: I can give you the answer but here are couple of links for you. How to [Refer to Cells by Using Index Numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa221540), How to [Avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Once you patiently go through the above links you will be able to spot the error and in fatc can come up with a better code than what you have above ;) Give it a try and if you get stuck simply post here.

Comment: I tried searching many times, it's just that I couldn't understand some codes maybe because I'm new in vba

Comment: I also tried Cells(i).Value.Copy but shows runtime error

Comment: Well you do not need to search anymore :) I already gave you 2 links above. Go trhough them

Comment: Yes I already read that It's just that I will not able to apply it in my codes since I didn't understand how to do/used it(just a newbie trying to learn more).

Comment: Which part from the first link which says `You can use the Cells property to refer to a single cell by using row and column index numbers...` you did not understand?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand how to apply it in my codes. My codes is only based on the tutorials I've watched

Comment: That link also has examples :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP wants a solution in a platter. Lack of effort to even patiently go through what the MSDN link and the SO link says.

Comment: I'm trying it's just that I'm stuck, anyway thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

For the beginning you should avoid all those activate stuff.
I gets a little confusing

- I think your problem lies in: Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy

Sub format()

```
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To a
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i, lColumn).Value Like "*application_id*" Then
    Temp = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,lColumn).value
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1) = Temp
End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Hi Lutscha, I revised my question, sorry I paste the wrong question earlier.